# How to access internet which requires manual IPv4 settings and LDAP-username-password login during Arch Linux installation?

Tags: installation, arch-linux, ipv4, ldap

I am on an university-network that requires me to manually set `IPv4` settings and then open an url on the browser to login with LDAP username and password to access internet.

I can connect to the `Hotspot` from my mobile-phone and proceed with `Arch Linux` installation. In fact I successfully installed `Arch Linux` one time this way, but this is both slow and expensive. Also, I feel one should learn how to overcome the above obstacle rather than avoiding it. So I want to learn the right way to connect to ethernet with these special constraints (which I presume wouldn't be very unusual given many universities network operate this way)!

I have been beating around the bush as I checked out the following Arch Wiki pages: [LDAP authentication](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/LDAP_authentication), [Network Configuration](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Network_configuration), [dhcpcd](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dhcpcd) - but frankly it is just too much and very overwhelming, for someone new.

Most YouTube tutorials operate under the premise that you plug in an ethernet cable and you connect to internet. They don't address my *specific* situation of having to:

1. Configure `IPv4` settings manually, and then
2. Have to open an url in browser and sign in there with proper credentials: LDAP username and password

to be able to access internet.

(For comparision, if I were to install say `Ubuntu`, I would pretty much proceed without connecting to the internet at all. And once all is set and done, I get easy graphical environments to modify necessary settings and login on a browser. With `Arch Linux` installation, I can imagine that I can somehow set the `IPv4` settings, but I am really scratching my head over how can I overcome the need to open an url in the browser and sign-in with proper credentials! Will it even be possible? What should I even search for on Google/ Arch-wiki?)

So how I can I access internet during the `Arch Linux` installation under these special constraints/ circumstances? Any help/ hints will be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Configure IPv4 settings manually,

You can do this [using the `ip` tool](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Network_configuration#IP_addresses) for one-time configurations.

```
ip addr add X.X.X.X/Y dev eth0

ip route add default via X.X.X.Z
```

Don't forget to configure a DNS resolver:

```
echo nameserver X.X.X.Z > /etc/resolv.conf
```

> Have to open an url in browser and sign in there with proper credentials

The Arch install USB comes with `elinks` preinstalled for a browser. Hopefully your network's portal page does not require JavaScript.

(If it does, boot a different live USB – such as Slax or Ubuntu – then use it to log in. Most likely the session will be tied to the IPv4 or MAC address, so it should carry over when you reboot to Arch again.)

Check if your university offers 802.1X (or WPA-Enterprise) authentication as an alternative. (For example, they might offer an `eduroam` Wi-Fi network.) The 802.1X username and password can be set up with wpa_supplicant for both Ethernet and Wi-Fi and doesn't require a browser.

Comment: Can you replace the dots with a dummy IP address? dots are seem to be misleading here.

Comment: "If it does, boot a different live USB – such as Slax or Ubuntu – then use it to log in. Most likely the session will be tied to the IPv4 or MAC address, so it should carry over when you reboot to Arch again." -- sounds promising! Will try...